# Reference CodeCommit Filename in CodeBuild buildspec

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I am trying to create a cloudformation stack from the CodeCommit repository. 
I have created build project in CodeBuild.

My Build Command is like this:

```
build:
    commands:
    - aws cloudformation create-stack 
        --stack-name SGStack 
        --template-body file://security_groups.template 
        --parameters ParameterKey=VPCID,ParameterValue=vpc-77092d1
```

I think I have problem with the '--template-body' command.

How can I reference file of codecommit repo in codebuild build command?

Comment: Is the file available to the CodeBuild environment? How did you create it and how do you pass artifacts into it? You can try adding a `ls` command and check the logs to see what files are present.

Comment: Yes, Milan file is available in CodeCommit repository. I haven't passed any artifacts for now. I think I am having a problem in build spec. can you please help me to find the right command for my build spec.

Comment: How does CodeBuild know about the files in the CodeCommit repo then? Did you do a checkout in the `install` or `pre_build` phases? If not, try connecting the CodeCommit and CodeBuild with CodePipeline - the pipeline, when configured, will pass in the artifact to CodeBuild for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your buildspec, try accessing the template using pwd or using CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR environment variable:

e.g.:

build:
    commands:
    - aws cloudformation create-stack 
        --stack-name SGStack 
        --template-body file://$(pwd)/security_groups.template 
        --parameters ParameterKey=VPCID,ParameterValue=vpc-77092d1